# Array Field in MongoDB Object is returned empty by Doctrine although it is not empty in DB

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a Symfony Application which uses a MongoDB and Doctrine to Connect the Application with the DB. 
But now I added a collection field to one of the documents but the content of this field is always empty when I query it from the database via PHP, although it is not empty, when I return it directly in the MongoDB Shell.

In more Detail:
I added a new field 'loginLast90Days' to the existing document 'User' to store the time integers in an array:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique as MongoDBUnique;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="users")
 * @MongoDBUnique(fields="{id, email}")
 */
class User
{
   // ...
   /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="collection")
     */
    protected $loginLast90Days;

    // ...

    /**
     * Set loginLast90Days
     *
     * @param collection $loginLast90Days
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setLoginLast90Days($loginLast90Days)
    {
        $this->loginLast90Days = $loginLast90Days;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get loginLast90Days
     *
     * @return collection $loginLast90Days
     */
    public function getLoginLast90Days()
    {
        return $this->loginLast90Days;
    }

    public function addLoginLast90Days($login)
    {
        $this->loginLast90Days[] = $login;
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLoginLast90Days($login)
    {
        $this->loginLast90Days->removeElement($login);
        return $this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now I can add a date integer to one of the user objects:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb');

            $user = $dm->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('gmail' => $email));

$user->addLoginLast90Days(time());

$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$dm->persist($user);
$dm->flush();
```

Now when I find the object using the Mongo Shell I can see the new value in the field. 
But the next time I add a value to the object, the array in PHP is empty, although I can see in the DB that it should not be empty.

Does anyone have an idea, where my mistake is? Am I forgetting to map the field to the db correctly or something?

Thanks so much in advance!

Edit: 
Here is the constructor of the User document:

```
public function __construct($customerId, $refreshToken, $canManageCustomers)
    {
        $this->customerId = $customerId;
        $this->refreshToken = $refreshToken;
        $this->canManageCustomers = $canManageCustomers;
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->accountLevel = "basic";
        $this->isRegistered = false;
        $this->createdAt = new \MongoDate();
    }
```

Comment: Can I see the constructor of your User entity ?

Comment: As you can see I do not initialise the array, but for some reason it stills appears correctly as an array in the MongoDB Shell. But I also tried with initialising inside the constructor as well as directly when declaring the variable `loginLast90Days`.

Comment: I am not too familiar with MongoDB but is it possible that you need to commit the new fields to the database before the php array fetches them?

Comment: As far as I understand it `$dm->flush()` commits als the changes to objects to the database. The mapping which parameter belongs to which field is defined using the MongoDB Annotations. Therefore any other kind of field (integer, date, etc.) is no problem. Only this collection comes back empty. Even other array collections to which I never add new values after they are created, work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your loginLast90Days as an Array,

initialize the attribute loginLast90Days in your constructor

```
public function __construct()
    {
        //Whatever you had here...
        $this->loginLast90Days = [];
    }
```

Comment: When I do this I get an "Collection type requires value of type array or null, Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given" MongoDB Error

Comment: You can't use `ArrayCollection` for `collection` type. Use plain array. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/300